# Unable to generate Kubernetes manifests yaml files using JKube maven plugin

Tags: java, kubernetes, nullpointerexception, maven-plugin, jkube

I'm trying to generate my Kubernetes manifests (`deployment.yml` and `service.yml`) using [JKube](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/) via this command : `mvn k8s:resource`

But I'm getting this error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< io.social.carpooling:trips-api >-------------------
[INFO] Building trips-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:resource (default-cli) @ trips-api ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.979 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-18T19:11:24+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:resource (default-cli) on project trips-api: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:resource failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Here is what my `pom.xml` looks like :

```
<properties>
        ...
        <jkube.version>1.1.1</jkube.version>
        <jkube.generator.name>my-dockerhub-username/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</jkube.generator.name>
        ...
</properties>
...
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jkube.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>my-dockerhub-username/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I tried to get more details using the plugin documentation but I didn't found so much.
Is there anyone who successfully generated the yaml files and deployed to Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Could you please remove `<images>` section and try again? I think it's caused by `<image>` field with no `<build>` configuration. It's a bug and we should fix this NPE

Comment: it doesn't let me to rename my generated Docker image.
Strangely when I put :
`<jkube.generator.name>docker.io/ghassenkhalil/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</jkube.generator.name>`
`k8s:build` generates under `target/docker/carpooling/trips-api` and the image is tagged like `carpooing/trips-api:latest instead of ghassenkhalil/trips-api`
and more, when I do `mvn k8s:push`, I get :
`Error while trying to push the image: Unable to push 'carpooling/trips-api:latest' : denied: requested access to the resource is denied`
because `carpooling/` is not the right path

Comment: Do you have some reproducer project which I can try out?

Comment: @RohanKumar here is the link for a reproducer project : https://github.com/ghassen1khalil/jkube-error-reproducer

Comment: Hello, I tried out your reproducer but couldn't reproduce NullPointerException. I could see `Deployment` getting generated but no `Service`. I noticed that there is no `EXPOSE` statement in your `Dockerfile`. You were not exposing any port in Docker image that's why jkube was not creating any service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Apparently this was a bug in Eclipse JKube([eclipse/jkube#624](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/issues/624)) that wasn't allowing users to configure image name using provided properties in simple Dockerfile mode. This has been fixed in new release [v1.2.0](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jkube/kubernetes-maven-plugin/1.2.0/).

Now you should be able to configure image name using `jkube.generator.name`. You don't need to provide XML configuration in order to override default image name. Earlier you're providing XML configuration without any `<build>` configuration which was causing this NPE. As per [Kuberntes Maven Plugin Documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin#_image_configuration) this field is mandatory when providing image XML configuration.
configuration
[image: image configuration docs table]

We're going to fix this NPE([eclipse/jkube#618](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/issues/618)) in upcoming releases too so that users can be informed when they don't provide a image build

Comment: Are you sure with this `pom.xml` you were able to override the image name ? For me I didn't work and it kept generating under `target/reproducer/` instead of `target/ghassenkhalil`

Comment: Hi, After cloning your project I only changed Dockerfile to include `EXPOSE` statement. Could you please try again by doing `mvn clean install` and then `mvn k8s:build`?

Comment: The build phase runs without problems but when I try to generate the yaml files even with the `EXPOSE` instruction I'm getting this error :
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:resource (default-cli) on project jkube-error-reproducer: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:resource failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
`

But when I add an empty `<build></build>` under `<image>` it runs correctly but now the problem is that the POD on my K8S cluster shows a `CrashLoopBackOff` error

Comment: ah, strange. Are you sure it's the same project as the one you  shared https://github.com/ghassen1khalil/jkube-error-reproducer

Comment: Could you please join us on our gitter chat so that we can debug your problem better: https://gitter.im/eclipse/jkube

Comment: Actually my main project is not github.com/ghassen1khalil/jkube-error-reproducer but I shared this once as you asked for the bug reproducer.
I will share the problem in the discussion at gitter.
You already told me to create an issue on Github previously and it was done :)